# Date Variable Formatting localisation

Tags: time, localization

I use `%l` in a Timestamp which results in eg. `Friday`. But since I'm on a Swiss server It should say `Freitag`. How do I set this to grab the correct translation? Is this a server thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running EE 2.6?

Comment: Yes I do.Oh I have to use 12 letters. well then…

Comment: Aren;t localization settings in EE controlled by the settings, not the server? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/date_localization.html

Comment: Yes. But the dates don't care about this setting. They remain english no matter what I choose there.